# Create dataframe from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello i have a problematic issue, i am working kind of big csv (average 600x1000, files which are produced by a software that i don't have acess to and sadly some of them are malformed :

[image]

dirt issue is when i use load the file with this code :

```
df=read_csv(csv_path,sep=';')
```

both cells circled in red are considered as column names so what i've done now is :

```
df=read_csv(csv_path,sep=';',names=None)
```

it worked exactly as i expected to ! But now here is my real problem i need to transpose this data frame and add real column names so here is my code :

```
df=read_csv(csv_path,sep=';',names=None)
col_names =["src_label"]
for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
    col_names.append("Result_"+str(i))
df=df.transpose()
data=df.to_dict
df1 = DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)
```

However i get the following error :

`ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

i've tried to call with

`df1 = DataFrame(df, columns=col_names)`

i also tried

`df.columns=col_names`

after having transposed it obviously but i has no effects
and i also tried
`df.names=col_names`
i got a warning saying 'can't set new values by creating an attribute'

and last try was :

```
for j in range(len(col_names)-1):
    df = df.rename_axis(col_names[i], axis=i)
```

no errors but no effects either

EDIT :
just tried to read csv like this :

`df=read_csv(csv_path,sep=';',header=None)`

and got

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 975`

To help me, i need a solution to create a fresh dataframe from the previous one and then adding the column names or dirctly add column names in the first datarame in order to get the following result :
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter when loading the csv?

Comment: Why do I think that you have set the separator incorrect(because its a CSV). Are you sure its `;` instead of `,` ?

Comment: @JenilDave yes i am sure it is `;`, @Henry i just did and i got the following error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 593 elements, new values have 2 elements` it still considers the two cells as colmun names

Comment: do you still get the error if you specify engine=python  in addition to the skiprows arg when loading the csv?

Comment: @el_bobo no the error does not appear, how ever at the following line when i do df.columns=col_names i got the error from my comment just above ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution :

```
df=read_csv(csv_path,sep=';',header=None,skiprows=[0])
df1=df.transpose()
col_names =["src_label"]
for i in range(len(df1.columns)-1):
    col_names.append("Result_"+str(i))
df1.columns=col_names
```

thanks to @HenryYik who put me on the track of `skiprows`

Comment: Hi, glad you got the answer but I have not helped you in `skiprows`. Credits to @Henry

Comment: oh yeah i missed ahah sorry

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you don't know whether an input file is "corrupted" or not.

To cope with this, define the following class performing custom
filtering of your input file:

```
class InFile:
    def __init__(self, infile):
        self.infile = open(infile)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            line = self.infile.readline()
            if not line:  # EOF
                self.infile.close()
                break
            if line.count(',') > 1:
                break
        return line
```

It "swallows" lines with a single comma or none.

Then read your CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(InFile('Input.csv'))
```

I tested the above code on:

- a "normal" CSV file,
- a "corrupted" file, with *00:00:00,500* in the first line.

In both cases I got a proper DataFrame.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, i've just tried it and i have a bug when reading the csv file : `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`